# Why must there only be one table in the parameters table? (Documentation)

Tags: feature-request, documentation, parameters-section

As I attempted to submit my topic in Python's documentation about the webbrowser module, I was frustrated with the "Parameters must be formatted as a two column table" error message. As shown in the image, the syntax section of the topic has 5 methods, each with parameters. Logically, I expected to be able to have 5 tables of parameters, one for each method. Because of the two column rule, I was not able to label each table with the method the parameters correspond with. Even worse, I can't simply make 5, two column tables. Because StackOverflow's markdown doesn't support merged cells in a table, I have no way of separating the parameters.

[image]

It is possible I could list each parameter from each method in the same table, however it does not prevent future cases where methods could have the same named parameter with different descriptions needed for the parameter. Would it not be more logical to allow multiple two column tables, possibly with labels?

**TL;DR**

Shouldn't the parameters section of documentation allow for multiple two column tables, one for each method in the syntax section, so that each method has its own set of separate parameter names/descriptions?